# field.function - KeyError: 40

Tags: odoo

Created a column 'line_no' when i updated the value it throws the KeyError: 40

My code:

```
def _get_line_no(self, cr, uid, ids, line_no, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):                     
        nextno =0
        no = record.next_line_no        
        next_no = nextno + no
        total =+ next_no
        res={
                  'next_line_no':next_no,
                  'line_no': total
        } 
    return res

_columns = {
 'line_no':fields.function(_get_line_no,string='Line No',type='integer'),
 'next_line_no':fields.integer(' Next Line No'),
  }
_defaults = {
    'next_line_no':1  
  }
```

Throws  Error : KeyError: 40

How do i resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next_line_no` is a database field, So it won't effect the dynamic way.

You need to modify this way,

```
def _get_line_no(self, cr, uid, ids, line_no, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):                     
        nextno =0
        no = record.next_line_no        
        next_no = nextno + no
        total += next_no
        res[record.id]={
                  'next_line_no':next_no,
                  'line_no': total
        } 
    return res

_columns = {
 'line_no':fields.function(_get_line_no,string='Line No',type='integer', multi="lineno"),
 'next_line_no': function(_get_line_no,string='Next Line No',type='integer', multi="lineno", store=True),
  }
_defaults = {
    'next_line_no':1  
  }
```

I hope this will yelp you.

Comment: @AtulArvind thanks please give +1, So it is useful for all users

Comment: @dhana as you wish. +1 is Free! :)

Comment: @dhana my answer proposes the same.

Comment: @AtulArvind yes 70% your answer is correct, But `next_line_no` not changed in your code.

Comment: @dhana, exactly that's where you beat me! I appreciate it.

Comment: @3156938 yes, then what ?

Comment: @dhana@ line_no not stored in db. How can i get the stored value (1,2,3..)in another class i.e if i use orderline.line_no , can get only this kind of value (1,1,1)

Comment: @3156938 not storing any more, Because your using static function logic and it is not stored in the database. If you want that put `store=True`

Comment: I tried, if store=true , cant get output structure. Is any possible can i assign this value into another field.

Comment: `'line_no': function(_get_line_no,string='Line No',type='integer', multi="lineno", store=True),`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the columns by,

```
_columns = {
    'line_no':fields.function(_get_line_no,string='Line No',type='integer', multi="line"),
    'next_line_no':fields.function(_get_line_no, type='integer', string='next line number' ,multi="line"),
}
```

and your method like,

```
def _get_line_no(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):                     
        nextno =0
        no = record.next_line_no        
        next_no = nextno + no
        total += next_no
        res[record.id]={
                  'next_line_no':next_no,
                  'line_no': total
        } 
    return res
```

This will work.

Comment: It doesnt enter into a for loop throws Error:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tracebacklimit'

Comment: oh! I misplaced + on "total += next_no"